# Are API calls possible using amp-story? Are there any examples?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

Are API calls possible using amp-story? Are there any examples for `<amp-story>`?

**Link to AMP Content**

*Use the AMP URL API to match URLs to corresponding AMP URLs, and serve the AMP versions instead.*

**Request an AMP URL via:**

*POST https://acceleratedmobilepageurl.googleapis.com/v1/ampUrls:batchGet*

The batchGet method returns the AMP URL mapping in JSON:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AMP URL API](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/reference/acceleratedmobilepageurl/rest/) is not intended to be called at runtime, but rather server-side.  `amp-story` imposes no restrictions to what you do server-side, so you may use this if you like.

Client-side, the only way, currently, to make a REST call within `<amp-story>` is by using [`<amp-list>`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list), which does not support `POST` requests.